# How to launch user application from gmrun

Tags: gmrun

I installed eclipse on ubuntu 10.04 by `copying eclipse folder to /opt folder`.

Now i would like to launch eclipse from gmrun dialog box by typing `eclipse`

How do i do that?

In windows to launch eclipse from run dialog box i copy the short cut of the application and paste it in windows/system32..Is there some thing like that in ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

Add this line to your `.bashrc`: `export PATH=/opt/eclipse:$PATH`, assuming the binary `eclipse` is inside `/opt/eclipse`.

It might be `/opt/eclipse/bin` or similar, but you will have to check it out yourself.

After that, you should be able to run it by pressing `Alt+F2` and entering `eclipse`.

Answer (score 0):

Typing `eclipse` at the command line calls a shell script in /usr/bin/ which then launches Eclipse. It looks like there's a line in the script you can change to point to your Eclipse install directory: `ECLIPSE=/usr/lib/eclipse/eclipse`.

Answer (score 0):

Create shortcut in `/usr/bin` or `/usr/local/bin` and it will work similarly as in Windows.

Comment: You should add more detail.  "Add a shortcut" really means what invocation of ln -s ?